# How to add horizontal scroll to mat autocomplete

Tags: css, angular, typescript, mat-autocomplete

I am running angular app , I have auto complete on this, I want to add horizontal scroll to the mat-option, I tried applying css style

```
.cdk-overlay-pane {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

 then applying syle as told in this docuemnt [enter link description here][1] showPanel: boolean

  <mat-option class="CustomerDropDown" showPanel="true" ...
```

```
extended question

<mat-form-field >
  <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"  [formControl]="customerFilterControl">
  <mat-autocomplete panelWidth ="450px" #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith] = "displayFn" style="width:750px;">
     <mat-option  *ngFor="let customer of filteredOptions | async" [value] ="customer.AccountID + '('+ customer.AccountName + ')'" (click)="onCustomerChange(customer)">
      {{customer.AccountID}} ({{customer.AccountName}})
     </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Both the attempts failed!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS. It worked for me.

```css
::ng-deep .custom-mat-option .mat-option-text {
  overflow: auto;
  text-overflow: unset;
  // color: green;
}
```

`custom-mat-option` is a class I have added to the `<mat-option>` element to increase the css specifity.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngdeep-css?file=src/main.ts)

Comment: Hi Chris your solution works in Stackblitz but in my app I don't find mat-option-text class at all, I am restricted in my application to use only angular6 . this might be the difference else solution is perfect

Comment: Which angular-material version do u use?

Comment: it is     "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",

Comment: According to the source of there should be a `mat-option` in Angular Material 6.4.x. (https://github.com/angular/components/blob/6.4.x/src/lib/core/option/option.html)
Do you use the `<mat-option>` element in your HTML? Can you extend your question with the HTML, which show the usage of the `mat-autocomplete`?

Comment: I do use mat-option to populate data, but I don't see mat-option-text

Comment: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/6.4.x/src/lib/core/option/option.html#L4

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" class="example-viewport">
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" class="example-item">{{item}}</div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

**TS File**

```
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Basic virtual scroll */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class CdkVirtualScrollOverviewExample {
  items = Array.from({length: 100000}).map((_, i) => `Item #${i}`);
}
```

**CSS**

```
.example-viewport {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.example-item {
  height: 50px;
}
```

and also follow this link
[scrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api)