# How to increase length of mat-autocomplete and get horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am running angular, precisely Angular6. I want to increase autocomplete length so I can show many customers and I also want horizontal scroll as customer names are shown only half.

How to achieve this, I did look at the mat-autocomplete documentation I didn't understand much. Any help is really appreciated.

[image]

**template.html**

```
<mat-form-field [style.cursor]="pointer" [style.cursor]="pointer" [style.width.px]=300  >
     <input class="selectCustomer" class="selectCustomerData" id="inputCustomer" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"  [formControl]="customerFilterControl" [(ngModel)]="customerName">
     <mat-icon matSuffix>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
       <p id="spandiv">{{customerName}}</p>  
     <mat-autocomplete dropdown-arrow="true" panelWidth ="450px" #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith] = "displayFn">
        <mat-option class="CustomerDropDown" *ngFor="let customer of filteredOptions | async"   [value] ="customer.AccountID +' '+'('+ customer.AccountName + ')'" (onSelectionChange)="onCustomerChange(customer)">
         {{customer.AccountID}} ({{customer.AccountName}})
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

**template.css**

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane {

     height:450px;
}
```

The above effort did not fetch me any result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add horizontal scroll to mat autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59067480/how-to-add-horizontal-scroll-to-mat-autocomplete)